# Streaming audio using Xamarin MediaManager

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android, audio-streaming

I am building an Android Xamarin app that uses [MediaManager](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager) to play audio.

Playing a local mp3 file or even a file onlie like this one : https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3 works just fine.

But i can't get it to play a stream from a link like this:  "http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/"

```
    private readonly IMediaManager mediaPlayer;
    public IMediaManager MediaPlayer => mediaPlayer;
    public IMediaQueue Queue => mediaPlayer.MediaQueue;
    public IMediaFile CurrentTrack => Queue.Current;
   //..
   mediaPlayer = CrossMediaManager.Current;
   //..
   Queue.Clear();
   var mediaUrls =
        new[] {                            
     "https://ia800806.us.archive.org/15/items/Mp3Playlist_555/AaronNeville-CrazyLove.mp3",
     "http://stream.radiosai.net:8002/"
   };

   foreach (var mediaUrl in mediaUrls)
   {
     Queue.Add(new MediaFile() { Type = MediaFileType.Audio, Url = mediaUrl });
   }
```

The first link works but the second doesn't, what i am missing here?

Ps: the full sample can be found [here](https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/tree/develop/Samples/Simple/MediaSample.Droid)

Comment: Generally speaking XamarinMediaManager project is pretty neglected...and to be frank it's pretty broken as well...the [latest version release](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Plugin.MediaManager/) happened ~7 months ago. We used it in one of our projects and initially we were fixing stuff and PR'ing it in. Later, there was so much bugs that we forked the repo and used completely custom version of it. I would strongly advise not to use it, if you're planning to rely on it heavily (e.g. podcast app)

Comment: Could you suggest any alternatives please ?

Comment: There's not much there (or nothing else tbh) in terms of cross platform solutions, but if you're looking only at the Android dev then you can have a look at the [audio sample](https://developer.xamarin.com/samples/monodroid/Example_WorkingWithAudio/) and maybe [this sample as well](https://github.com/xamarin/recipes/tree/master/Recipes/android/media/audio/play_audio). Besides that, just read through the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media/mediaplayer).

Comment: Thank you, i will definitely take a look at those, unfortunately now, its's too late to rollback, i need at least to find a workaround

Comment: I wonder, have you tried adding that url with port defined as the first item in the queue? I remember, when working with XamarinMediaManager, we saw some issues with Queue itself - just a wild guess.

Comment: Yes i did, i put it alone on the queue but that didn't help.  We did open an issue on the repo  but i doubt that it will get much attention :/ 
https://github.com/martijn00/XamarinMediaManager/issues/382

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried with Exoplayer?

```
((MediaManagerImplementation)CrossMediaManager.Current).MediaSessionManager = new MediaSessionManager(Application.Context, typeof(ExoPlayerAudioService));
var exoPlayer = new ExoPlayerAudioImplementation(((MediaManagerImplementation)CrossMediaManager.Current).MediaSessionManager);
CrossMediaManager.Current.AudioPlayer = exoPlayer;
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, yes in fact i did, and got the same result !

Comment: I unable to use this in MainActivity. Show error with MediaSessionManager. It is ambiguous reference between Plugin.MediaManager.MediaSession and Android.Media.Session. I used both but error persist.

Answer (score 0):

The problem seems to be that you are not waiting long enough for the MediaManager (i.e. underlying ExoPlayer) to be initialized.
Try to enlist to this event:

```
MediaManager.Current.PropertyChanged += propertyChanged;
```

And then, this is what I do:

```
private void propertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "IsInitialized")
    {
        init();
    }
}
```

I just found out about my error/solution, so there may be a more elegant solution..
But I got rid of the exception - yay